# How to allow login with fosuserbundle by sending username and password in querystring

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, fosuserbundle

I am looking to allow users to bypass the login form and instead login by sending the username and password right in the querystring, could anyone point me in the right direction where I should start overriding/hacking the fosuserbundle? =)

Or must I write my own login controller all together?

Comment: Be careful if you include the password in the query string! This decreases the security of your users. For example, the plain password is automatically stored in the browser history.

Comment: Please explain why you want to do this, there might be a better/easier? way.

Comment: Part of my app is where the media servers log in against the Site and fetch their contents. This is of course done automatically, no human present. Each server also reboots every night. A lot easier to start the browser (which displays the slide show) and just point it to a url than to try and macro a form submission. Also, these accounts don't have privileges beyond viewing the slide show so it is no great security risk as i see it. Perhaps I could create a second login Page that submits the form automatically, and store credentials in the media servers browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I will do is, like I said in my comment, rely on the browser's username/password remember function, and put a value in the querystring like ?autoLogin=true which will then activate a javascript that submits the form once page is loaded. Thus relying on the browser to remember the password for the mediaserver.

Comment: To clarify - I put the credentials in querystring, then use a javascript onload to pull those variables from querystring, place in form and trigger the submit =) As discussed above, this is a real security breach if the browser is configured to display the URL, or if a human gains access to the machine (in our case won't happen). Still a security issue since querystring is passed in plain text across the web as discussed above. Just wanted to explain what I am doing and why, beware if you consider this solution.